# Firebase deploy only deploys functions but not hosting?

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting, firebase-cli

When I run `firebase deploy`, only my functions are deployed, but not my hosting.

```
=== Deploying to 'project1'...

i  deploying functions
i  functions: ensuring necessary APIs are enabled...
✔  functions: all necessary APIs are enabled
i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...
i  functions: packaged functions (36.04 KB) for uploading
✔  functions: functions folder uploaded successfully
i  functions: updating Node.js 6 function exampleFn1(us-central1)...
✔  functions[exampleFn1(us-central1)]: Successful update operation. 

✔  Deploy complete!
```

I thought it was an issue with build so ran `yarn build`, but hosting is still not being deployed.

On the Firebase console Hosting's release history section, it also shows latest deployment as January:

[image]

Any thoughts on why my React app is not being deployed? I've deployed it before and just made some front end and function changes.

(edit)

After running `firebase init` > hosting again which produced by firebase.json file, the deployment went through! But the deployed version is not the same version as `yarn serve` or even `firebase serve` serves up. Why is this?

```
=== Deploying to 'project1'...
i  deploying hosting
...
✔  Deploy complete!
```

Comment: Actually, it seems to have just taken a really long time. After deploying 3 more times it updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to modify firebase.json files and then provide the correct hosting parameters for example:-

```
 "hosting": {
    **"public": "www",**
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        **"source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"**
      }
    ]
  }
```

Now change **"public":"www" to "public":your dist folder name** and then perform firebase deploy.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you didn't select hosting in initializing firebase.